# Vimeo API: cannot delete because official SDK is using a wrong url

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

### Environment

- Debian 9
- PHP 7.2
- Vimeo package version in `composer.json`: "vimeo/vimeo-api": "^3.0.2"

  - resolved as version `3.0.2`

### The goal

Given a vimeo content url, delete the video. For example: having a video `https://vimeo.com/12345678` I want to delete the video with the id `12345678`

### What I am doing

**1. Instanciate the php sdk api client**

```
$client = new Vimeo(
   config('dyamer.vimeo_client_id'),
   config('dyamer.vimeo_client_secret'),
   config('dyamer.vimeo_access_token')
);
```

> This configs are right, I'm using to upload videos and all works

**2. Call the delete api endpoint**

```
$uri="https://vimeo.com/12345678";
$response = $client->request($uri, [], 'DELETE');
```

### The exception

The last row of code is throwing an absurd exception:

```
[Could not resolve host: api.vimeo.comhttps] 
in /...project_folder.../vendor/vimeo/vimeo-api/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php:527
Stack trace:
#0 /...project_folder.../vendor/vimeo/vimeo-api/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php(149): Vimeo\Vimeo->_request('https://api.vim...', Array)
```

> The last row is litterally showed with url trunced, it's not my fault on copy/pasting, but I think **this demonstrate that something is wrong inside Vimeo SDK**

### Questions

- Is it happening only to me?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- How can I circument this problem?

### Side notes

I already opened an [issue on Gihhub](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/issues/223), without any official reply from sdk developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succesfully traced the error to an error **of mine**

This is the incriminated snippet [actually on github here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php#L124-L138)

```
            case 'DELETE':
                if ($json_body && !empty($params)) {
                    $headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
                    $body = json_encode($params);
                } else {
                    $body = http_build_query($params, '', '&');
                }
                $curl_url = self::ROOT_ENDPOINT . $url;
                $curl_opts = array(
                    CURLOPT_POST => true,
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body
                );
                break;
```

Dumping the `$curl_url` I see

```
https://api.vimeo.comhttps://vimeo.com/12345678
```

Is is obviously wrong.

From [official api doc about DELETE](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#delete_video)

> REQUEST
>
> DELETE https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}

So error **is entirely mine**

### Wrong

```
$uri="https://vimeo.com/12345678";
$response = $client->request($uri, [], 'DELETE');
```

### Right

```
$uri="videos/12345678";
$response = $client->request($uri, [], 'DELETE');
```

> *Sorry, Vimeo staff, it was **my** fault, not yours.*